# GitHub Webhook - payload on "edited" action doesn't contain the new body

Tags: github, github-api, webhooks

I am trying to get the (new) body from an edited issue comment. I don't know if I am missing something here, but it seems that the webhook payload returned with an edited issue comment, contains only the old comment... There is no way to tell what was changed.

What I do at the moment, is when I get an issue comment event with an action "edited", to make a get request for this comment in order to retrieve its body.

Is this how it's supposed to be? I find it strange that I need to make a new request for something that should already be in the issue comment payload.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a call you are making, what it is returning and what you expect it to return?

Comment: It should be under `changes` according to https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#issuecommentevent

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The "changes" has the previous comment (before the edit) not the latest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with webhook content returning old data, presumably due to caching and/or replication issues in GitHub's backend. GitHub support themselves have confirmed to me that this can happen.

The only workaround right now is to fetch the comment content in a separate API request after some small delay in order to allow the updated comment body to propagate through GitHub's backend (the bug affects API requests as well as webhook events, annoyingly).

Comment: Thanks for the info kfb !